# technique and implications for implementing this example as a prototype function?

Tags: javascript

I've created several variance-color lookup objects in js.  Different elements will have different variance-colors:

```
    var varianceColorTable =
    {
        Ranges:
        [
            //decrease
            { From: -10000, To: -1.01, Color: '#595959' },
            { From: -1.00, To: -0.01, Color: '#999999' },
            //no change
            { From: 0.00, To: 0.00, Color: '#FFFFFF' },
            //increase
            { From: 0.01, To: 1.00, Color: '#BABC16' },
            { From: 1.01, To: 10000, Color: '#576A2D' }
        ]
    }

    return getColor(varianceColorTable, range);

    function getColor()
    {
        var rangeColor = $.grep(varianceColorTable.Ranges, function (n, i) {
            return variance >= n.From && variance <= n.To;
        })[0].Color;
    }
```

This code is defined within a VarianceColorLookupManager.js module.  Can I define a prototype function within this module so getColor(range) would be a function off of the object?  For example:

```
    return {
        Ranges:
        [
            //decrease
            { From: -10000, To: -1.01, Color: '#595959' },
            { From: -1.00, To: -0.01, Color: '#999999' },
            //no change
            { From: 0.00, To: 0.00, Color: '#FFFFFF' },
            //increase
            { From: 0.01, To: 1.00, Color: '#BABC16' },
            { From: 1.01, To: 10000, Color: '#576A2D' }
        ]
    }.getColor(varianceColorTable, range);
```

If this is possible then would it be possible to make the getColor() object prototype function local to the js module if it isn't already by default?

Comment: What does "*local to the js module"* mean?

Comment: If you want to do a.b().c() look up Javascript method chaining. This question is too vague to answer at the moment.

Comment: For example, the getColor() prototype function would not be available to a user object in a different js module

Comment: Why do you pass `getColor(varianceColorTable, range);`? Your `getColor` function takes no parameters! (Although it really should. That's the first step to the solution)